# When a user Like my page embeded in my site some functions should call

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, facebook, facebook-like

I have a simple site, I want to code that when ever a user on my site Like my Page which is embeded in it another button should appear below it saying "Proceed to Next Step"
Hope so you got my idea.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  A jquery script would probably accomplish what your wanting to do.

Comment: at least show some effort.  If you haven't tried anything at all you should at least start by googling to find your answer.  Majority of the time your going to find something to get you started, then when you can't get that working come here and ask why it's not working and people will be more than happy to help you get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in essence, you have to use the FB API to achieve what you want. Here is the example:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) 
    {
        //Liked event - do something here
        $('#something').show();
    });
    };

    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

});
```

Comment: Actually I'm starter at jQuery. If you can make it easy or just a brief info about it I would really appreciate it. Actually I would like to add a entry of a person who liked the page.